# Android Studio Startup Error 'PluginManagerCore.getEnabledPluginRawList()' on Windows 10

Tags: android

I wanted to check something up but after updating Windows 10 to October 2020 Update, Android Studio faces this error currently with my JDK.

```
Internal error. Please refer to https://code.google.com/p/android/issues

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'java.util.List 
com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManagerCore.getEnabledPluginRawList()'
at com.a.c.c.d.a1.a(a1.java:127)
at com.a.c.c.d.a1.a(a1.java:76)
at com.a.c.c.d.aC.a(aC.java:56)
at com.intellij.idea.MainImpl.start(MainImpl.java:19)
at com.intellij.idea.StartupUtil.lambda$startApp$5(StartupUtil.java:248)
at com.intellij.util.ui.EdtInvocationManager.executeWithCustomManager(EdtInvocationManager.java:73)
at com.intellij.idea.StartupUtil.startApp(StartupUtil.java:243)
at com.intellij.idea.StartupUtil.prepareApp(StartupUtil.java:214)
at com.intellij.ide.plugins.MainRunner.lambda$start$0(MainRunner.java:45)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:830)

-----
JRE 13.0.2+8 amd64 by Oracle Corporation
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-13.0.2
```

Can I somehow fix this issue?

Edit: I firstly looked for similar errors, but like no one faced this error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out how to fix it: I had to simply delete the ".AndroidStudio4.0", then I can continue on with my projects and stuff.

Answer (score 1):

By the way, path to ".AndroidStudio4.0" directory is "C:\Users\[USERNAME]".